# "'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable" error

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that sorts words in alphabetical order, and this code fragment gives me an error. I don't know why this is happening, I don't see anything wrong here. Can someone please help?

```
for k in range(x):
    a = wordlist[k].lower

    for key, value in alphabet.items():
        if value == i:
            alphabetkey = key[:]
            break

    if a[0:0] == alphabetkey: #specifically this line
        temp.append(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if a[0:0] == alphabetkey: #specifically this line
```

Is causing the issue.

```
    a = wordlist[k].lower
```

Is defining `a` as a function. You want that function's value so change it to

```
    a = wordlist[k].lower()
```

Comment: thanks. im starting to think im not made for such things

Comment: Don't worry the beginning  is the hardest part and you will get used to it.